# ASP.NET MVC 5 generates right url but executes wrong Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-routes

I got a custom routes created for 2 different actions in same controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "editEquivPack",
    url: "equivpacks/{id}/{ecommerceid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "EquivPacks", action = "Edit" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "addEquivPack",
    url: "equivpacks/add/{ecommerceid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "EquivPacks", action = "Add" }
);
```

In a

```
URL.RouteURL("addEquivPack", ecommerceid = Model.EcommerceID)
```

it generates a correct URL:

```
http://localhost:53365/EquivPacks/Add/1
```

But when i try to navigate there, it sends me a error message:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32, Int32)' in 'XXXXXXX.Controllers.EquivPacksController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

It seems that it executes `Edit` action and not `Add` action that is the action configured in route map.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of route definitions is important and the first match wins. Your first route definition (`editEquivPack`) means *match a url containing 3 segments, where the first segment is "equivpacks"*.

Your url of `../EquivPacks/Add/1` matches that, so it then calls the `Edit()` method and passes a value of `"Add"` to your `int id` parameter in that method (which cannot be bound to an `int`, hence the error).

You need to change the order of your routes so that the `addEquivPack` route is before the `editEquivPack` route.